how to solve differential equation $2x^2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan{(x^2y^2)}-2xy^2$
I have studied on some equations in my research and i arrived at this differential equation $2x^2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan{(x^2y^2)}-2xy^2$ which can cross from $(1, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}})$so can anyone help me to solve it?

What have you tried so far? (Notice that $2 x^2 y y' + 2 x y^2$ can be rewritten more compactly using a standard observation.)

You've been around for a while, please include your effort

I would start with $u = x^2y^2.$  This becomes pretty easy to solve after that substitution.

Take $x^2y^2=u$. Then using the ODE you have, you get
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 2x^2 y \frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy^2 = \tan{x^2y^2} = \tan{u}.$$
Now it can be solved easily right ?
